# Outputing data to .txt file in matlab has error

Tags: matlab

The *c:\answer2.txt* file data looks like 3957.7913 11618.2937 72.56 3957.7913 11618.2937 72.56 ......(GPGGA format:latitude, longitude and height).

I want to convert the data to decimal: 39.963188 116.304895 72.56 ......

The code has an error in line 19:Error in ==> earth at 19
*fprint(fp,'%f %f %f ',X2(i),Y2(i),Z2(i))*; (tip:earth is matlab script name)

How can I modify the code to avoid this error?

The file that has been handled has latitude, longitude and height coordinates which are GPGGA(one type of NMEA) format. Matlab will show these coordinates in decimal instead of degree, minute.

```
 fid = fopen('c:\answer2.txt');
 [A, count] = fscanf(fid,'%f ',inf);
 fid1=['earth','.txt'];
 fp=fopen(fid1,'wt');
 B=reshape(A,3,count/3);
 X=B(1,:);%ddmm.mmmm latitude coordinate
 Y=B(2,:);%        longitude coordinate
 Z=B(3,:);%          height coordinate
 X2=(X-3900)/60+39;
 Y2=(Y-11600)/60+116;
 Z2=Z;
 for i=1:count/3
     fprint(fp,'%f %f %f ',X2(i),Y2(i),Z2(i));
 end
 fclose(fp);
 fclose(fid);
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: fprint(fp,'%f %f %f ',X2(i),Y2(i),Z2(i))

Comment: I mean the actual message you read in the console, not the line of code that is problematic

Comment: I want to output X2(1),then Y2(1), Z2(1),after that,  X2(2),then Y2(2), Z2(2). There is a whitespace between two element.

Comment: The actual message is included by a .txt file. Just like :3957.7923 11618.2949 73.99 3957.7923 11618.2949 73.98 3957.7923 11618.2949 73.99 3957.7923 11618.2949 74.00  .......many numbers

Comment: I think you probably want [fprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to print a formatted string, not `fprint`

Comment: @tmpearce Yes, I think so. But how could I  modify it?

Comment: Just type an extra `f` after `fprint` so it becomes `fprintf` instead...

Comment: @tmpearce You have solved my problem. I change fprint to fprintf, then everything is OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change fprint to fprintf. If so, anything should be OK

Comment: trying to get Self-Learner badge?

Comment: @brodroll how to do? I am a newcomer.

Comment: Just write: "As @tmpeace suggested, ..."